# How can I hide exposed filter control if the filter is not applicable to existing views results?

Tags: views

I have created a view with three exposed filters. Now I have to hide these Fields dynamically - if field is not present in any of the content types of the nodes in current result, filter based on this field should not be visible. I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a small module or add a function into template.php where you use a one of the hook alter functions. You test your view results for a given set, and if you at that result don't need the filter you unset it. Probably the best hook is: hook_views_pre_render.

"https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_hooks/7"

Check out the comments on the hook_views_pre_render function to get an idea of how to use it. Hope this gets you on your feet.